# iis 7 handler error

Tags: iis

The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

This is the error that i get when trying to load an asp file from iis 7.0

I am using windows vista home basic

I got to know that the solution for this is to enable the static file handler

also, there is no file handler installed in vista home basic ........Can anyone help to get rid of this please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the ASP feature for IIS7 is installed by default, so you may need to install and configure it if you haven't already.

These links explain what you need to do to setup ASP support in IIS7:

1. [Configuring ASP on IIS7](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/02/18/running-classic-asp-on-iis-7.aspx)
2. [Tips for ASP on IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx)